# How to perform aggregate function on last 4 rows of data?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, aggregate-functions

I've got a table off the following model.

```
public class WeeklyNums
{
   public int FranchiseId { get; set; }
   public DateTime WeekEnding { get; set; }
   public decimal Sales { get; set; }
}
```

I need a fourth column that calculates the minimum for this week and the previous three weeks.  So the output would look like this.

```
1   7-Jan   $1  
1   14-Jan  $2  
1   21-Jan  $3  
1   28-Jan  $4  **1**  
1   4-Feb   $4  **2**  
1   11-Feb  $6  **3**  
1   18-Feb  $4  **4**  
1   25-Feb  $8  **4**  
1   3-Mar   $7  **4**
```

I have no idea where to even start.  Even some help with solving it in SQL would be helpful.

thx!

Comment: How do you define "this week"? What calendar rules are you using to define your weeks? Or do you just want the newest values in the database, even if they aren't for this week?

Comment: Wouldn't the last record for the 3rd of March have a min value of 4 instead of 6?

Comment: the weekending is every sat, so you could sub select on previous 28 days.  but I'd like to do it by record so I can apply it elsewhere, if possible.

Comment: sql 2008 r2 is the sql version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm too late, but here's the linq version:

```
var result = from w1 in db.Table
             from w2 in db.Table.Where(x => x.WeekEnding >= w1.WeekEnding.AddDays(-28))
             select new
             {
                 FranchiseId = w1.FranchiseId,
                 WeekEnding = w1.WeekEnding,
                 Sales = w1.Sales,
                 SalesMin = w2.Min(x => x.Sales)
             };
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `outer apply`:

```
select  yt1.*
,       hist.four_week_min
from    YourTable yt1
outer apply
        (
        select  min(col1) as four_week_min
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt2.dt between dateadd(wk, -3, yt1.dt) and yt1.dt
        ) hist
```

Working example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01764/4).

Comment: Nice!  I'll try it out in linqpad now.

Comment: I don't think Linq2Sql supports `apply`.

Comment: @DabuekEli - One hitch in this approach is that assumes that the previous three entries are also three weeks apart as opposed to the three entries with a data prior to the given entry. E.g., suppose the previous three entries are `{2012-05-01,1},{2012-05-02,5},{2012-05-03,5},{2012-05-04,5}`. This query will return `1` instead of `5`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var runningMins =   from weekNum in data
                    select new
                               {
                                   FranchiseId = weekNum.FranchiseId,
                                   WeekEnding = weekNum.WeekEnding,
                                   Sales = weekNum.Sales,
                                   LastThreeWeeks = data.OrderByDescending( x => x.WeekEnding )
                                        .Where( x => x.WeekEnding <= weekNum.WeekEnding )
                                        .Take( 4 )
                                        .Min( x => x.Sales )
                               };
```

SQL Query that will return minimum of the current and the three previous regardless of whether the dates are exactly three weeks apart:

```
With RnkItems As 
  (
    Select DateVal, Sales
      , Row_Number() Over ( Order By DateVal ) As Rnk
    From SourceData
    )
Select *
  , (
    Select Min(Sales)
    From  RnkItems As R1
    Where R1.Rnk Between R.Rnk - 3 And R.Rnk
    )
From RnkItems R
Order By 1
```

[SQL Fiddle version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb998/7)